com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired
When I get the facebook token and submit it to firebase, it prompts failure.
The news is (The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired. Exception description
I have configured it according to the tutorial, but it still fails(Input1 Input2)
